# How to POST formData and another data in axios

Tags: ajax, laravel, vue.js, axios

If it's just formData, I can send it.
But if you put other data together, formData will be empty.

```
const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', files);

      axios.post('/api/upload', {
        formData,
        route: this.$route.params.test
        }, {
          headers: {
            'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
          }}).then(response => {
        console.log(response);
      });
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: What is _other data_? Can you create a [mre]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use it like this

```
const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', files);

  axios.post('/api/upload', {
    data:formData,
    /* what is this ? If you want this to be on form data use formData.append('route', this.$route.params.test) */
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
      }}).then(response => {
    console.log(response);
  });
```